# How to enable both internal reordering and external dropping in a Qt widget?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have created a widget which inherits `QListWidget`.

My goal is for it to accept files dropped into it from an external file manager, and for the user to be able to reorder the elements in the widget. I can achieve both, but not at the same time.

If I just set

```
myWidget->setDragDropMode(QListView::InternalMove);
myWidget->setDragEnabled(true);
```

I can reorder the items within the widget, but I can't drop external items into it.

If I reimplement the `dragMoveEvent`, `dragEnterEvent` and `dropEvent` events, all of them just having `acceptProposedAction();` and some debug messages inside them, I can drop external files into my widget, but I can no longer rearrange the items.

Is there a way to have the above two at the same time, or do I have to manage the items myself in the reimplemented functions? If so, how can I know if a dropped item is internal or external, and how can I know from which position it was taken and into which position in the list it was dropped into?

If I parse the mimeData which I got from the event, I can see whether it as a file or a text, and I get "qabstractitemmodeldatalist" if it was an internal item, but it still doesn't give me its position.

I can check `event->pos()` to know in pixels where the drop has been made, and `event->source()` to learn about what was dropped there, but is this really best practice, to start calculating pixel values and adding objects "manually"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple: I just had to call the functions of the parent class at the end of each function I've overridden.

```
void myWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    do_stuff_with_received_data(event);

    QListWidget::dropEvent(event);
}
```